# Can I install two versions of libbullet?

Tags: apt, shared-library

I use ubuntu 12.04

My error msg:

```
sam@sam:~/code/pcl_standalone/vfh_dir$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libbullet
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libbullet
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/963 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2456 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 796153 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libbullet (from .../libbullet_2.80-0_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libbullet_2.80-0_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/libHACD.so.2.80', which is also in package libbullet2.80 2.80.2-ubuntu1~precise1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libbullet_2.80-0_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
sam@sam:~/code/pcl_standalone/vfh_dir$
```

How to solve it?

Comment: All the methods in this thread do not work for me. Any suggestions? Thank you~

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

You can't have two versions of libaries, like libbullet in the same system. Remove one of them. I presume you are using a PPA. If that's the case contact the PPA maintainer.

To remove them:

```
sudo dpkg -r libbullet2.80
```

or

```
sudo dpkg -r libbullet
```

The maintainers of PPA's are only reached by mail, normally.